# How to require a specific character set in Spring WS?

Tags: web-services, soap, character-encoding, spring-ws

We have a SOAP Web Service using Spring WS. We would like to have all requests with a certain encoding/character set. The reasons we would like to have only one encoding/character set are:

- the encoding/character set fits our market perfectly
- accepting full Unicode would introduce a lot of scripts which don't make sense in our market and we can't handle in a meaningful way
- supporting full Unicode correctly would require a lot of work in terms of normalization, ordering, sorting, searching and so on

Ideally we would like to check the request in one central place instead of having to check each string individually.

Is there a better way to implement this other than a servlet filter? We're not that happy with a servlet filter because Spring WS seems to operate on the input stream of the request which may ignore the encoding in the header. Which means we would have to peek into the body.